# laravel5.2 how to get value from multiple checkbox

Tags: html, laravel-5

```
@foreach($items as $item)
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_delete[]" value="{{$item->item_num}}" /></td>
        <td>{!! $item->item_num !!}</td>
        <td>{!! \App\Category::where('cat_id',$item->model)->first()->cat_name !!}</td>
        <td>{!! \App\Category::where('cat_id',$item->model)->first()->selling_price !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $item->color !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $item->production_year !!}</td>
        <td>
            <a style="width: 80%"
               href="{!! action('CategoriesController@edit', $item->model) !!}">Edit</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <a href="{!! action('ItemsController@edit', $item->item_id) !!}"
                   class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td width="8%">
            <div>
                <a href="{!! action('ItemsController@delete', $item->item_id) !!}"
                   class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirmDelete();">Delete</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'/entry/print/bar-code/'.$item->item_num)) !!}
        <td width="8%">
            <div>
                {!!Form::number('numToPrint'.$item->item_num,null,array('class'=>'form-control pull-right','placeholder'=>'Number of Copies To Print','style'=>'width:100%','id'=>'numToPrint'.$item->item_num)) !!}
            </div>
        </td>
     <td width="8%">

   <div><button href="{!! action('ItemsController@printBarCode', $item->item_num) !!}" class="btn btn-primary">Print</button>
            </div>
        </td>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
<td width="8%">
    <div>
        <a href="{!! action('ItemsController@delete_by_checks') !!}"
           class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return confirmDelete();">Delete by checks</a>
    </div>
</td>
</table>
@endif
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('entry/delete/item', ['uses' => 'ItemsController@delete_by_checks']);
```

The problem when i click on delete by checks and when write `dd($request->check_delete)` i get 0.I tried to put delete by checks in form but not work.

I want when click on delete by checks I get all value for the items checked .this problem tired me ,please any one tell me how to solve,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put your checkbox inside your form, of you won't be able to access it from the `$request` object.

Just put `{!! Form::open !!}` after `<tr>` and `{!! Form::close() !!}` before `</tr>`